# The type org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities is not accessible

Tags: selenium, file, testing, mobile, jar

Add all libraries
still showing error (in class path) ( selenium-standalone 3.14 ) (java-client)

[image: see]

[image]

Comment: Can anyone tell me the solution

Comment: What error are you getting? post the full error message.

Comment: now, error is (AndriodDriver is not working this is showing error)

    AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver ( new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub") , cap);